# "Clean" way to interrupt a thread which could be doing something

Tags: java, multithreading, interrupt

Ok, let's say I have a Thread which executes a while() loop. During the loop, could do something and then go back to sleep:

```
public void run() {
    while (some_condition) {
        doSomeLongJob();      // this could be a long job
        try {
            Thread.sleep(a_bit);    // back to sleep
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            handleInterruptionButDoNotExitLoop();
        }
    }
}
```

Some questions:

1. if some interruption comes during the execution of **doSomeLongJob**, the method will continue to its natural end? (I suppose yes as long as no-one checks for *Thread.interrupted()* but I'd like a confirm);
2. after catching the interruption, will the *interrupted()* status be reset to false?
3. in conclusion, a Thread can be interrupted *n* times as long as thread status is reset? is there a way to reset manually thread status in order to handle the interruption during the execution of **doSomeLongJob**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your questions:

1. When you say interruption do you mean InterruptedException? If so, I think you should move **doSomeLongJob** inside the try to handle the possible exception.
2. It will not be reset to false, you have to do it manually.
3. To reset the interrupted status, please call Thread.interrupted() .

Comment: yes I mean when InterruptedException happens... But let's say, for instance, that I move doSomeLongJob into the try/catch block. What happens to execution if an InterruptedException fires? (i.e., someone calls Thread.interrupt()). Is there a way to rollback what has been done up to now in doSomeLongJob?

Comment: Methods that throw an InterruptedException should reset the interrupted flag to false.  Thread.sleep() will do that.

Comment: @Ema given that the method is in the middle of execution, I'd say you have to do the rollback yourself but this will be tricky if the interrupt originated from outside your method.

Comment: @Michael Krussel I don't think that Thread.sleep() will reset the flag if that's what you meant, it can throw the exception though. To reset you need Thread.interrupted().

Comment: @IanGil The documentation for Thread.sleep specifies that the flag is cleared when an InterruptedException is thrown.  All methods in the standard library clear the interrupted status when throwing an InterruptedException.

Comment: @MichaelKrussel ahhhh... when the exception is thrown, then the flag is cleared/reset. Yes you are right.

Answer (score 1):

By calling `Thread.interrupted()` you get the status of the flag and then clear it.

My advice is: if in doubt call this method to make it clear (to the people who have to maintain the code later) that you want to absorb the condition and carry on.

Answer (score 1):

1. Maybe, if `doSomeLongJob` has open `InterruptibleChannel` IO objects, they will throw a `ClosedByInterruptException` next time you will try to access them if threads interrupt state is not cleared.
2. When `InterruptedException` is thrown by Java core classes, the thread interrupt state is not set
3. `Thread.interrupted` will clear the interrupt state.  If you just need a test for interrupt, `Thread.isInterrupted` will give you the status and preserve the interrupt state.